Blender FBX exports texture nodes incorrectly
When I export my Object as an FBX with a material using maps, the textures get jumbled in the process and connect to the wrong ports.

In the image, I use a diffuse, specular and normal map for the material. Alpha is set to 1.0 standard.
After re-importing, the diffuse texture shows up twice and its alpha port is connected to the object's alpha input.
And that's just, i don't know how to put it, plain wrong and quite puzzling.
I tried deactivating the node wrangler add-on.
I tried deleting the duplicate diffuse texture from the FBX, export that, and upon re-import, it is there again. It also happens when the texture is called something else than "diff", like "base color".
I'll be glad for information what's causing this?
Have this problem in 4.0 and 4.2 .
